# Не получается растянуть на весь footer. Как исправить?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<footer class="navbar-fixed-bottom">
<img class="img footer-wraper img-responsive img-fluid" src="{% static 'gallery/image/BG/bg-footer.png' %}">
```

Как растянуть изображение на весь футер? Использовал только классы библиотеки bootstrap4.

Comment: Подскажите, Вы посмотрели мой предыдущий ответ?

Comment: Возможно, у какого-то div фиксированная ширина,  и верстка чуть выпирает

Comment: @Denis640Kb Всё верно

Comment: @SumskyiVasyl Врядли. Ибо сам футер на всю ширину сайта, только изображение, которое находится внутри футера, не на всю ширину.

Comment: @ЭрнстКраузе. Можете показать параметры css футера?

Comment: @ЭрнстКраузе css в студию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```css
.footer {
    background-image: url('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/QMf5RElgFtAdTgYGAXg_T_27QUnCjAwN8C4-oJXzsKCrAOLTkay6M1kUOPeUPDFhAUD1n8assFol8QhPWbcbkm1rORHtPZ-y3gih=w3840-h2160-p-k-no-nd-mv');
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer"/>
```

Или в вашем случае со вложенным img можно попробовать так:

```css
.footer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <img src='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/QMf5RElgFtAdTgYGAXg_T_27QUnCjAwN8C4-oJXzsKCrAOLTkay6M1kUOPeUPDFhAUD1n8assFol8QhPWbcbkm1rORHtPZ-y3gih=w3840-h2160-p-k-no-nd-mv' class='image' />
</footer>
```

Comment: <footer class="navbar-fixed-bottom footer-wraper">
    <img class="img footer-wraper img-responsive img-fluid" src="{% static 'gallery/image/BG/bg-footer.png' %}">
</footer>

Добавил ещё класс на изображение от bootstrap и теперь при изменении разрешения сайта, footer так же изменяет разрешение. Но благодаря вам помогло, спасибо вам большое.

Comment: Рад, что у вас получилось. Так держать!